# Glut of dolphin meat in Japan going into pet food?

Tags: economics, japan, dolphins

Is there any truth behind the claim that Japan doesn't need all the dolphin meat it gets and the excess is being passed off to the pet food industry because there is little demand for the meat or they are producing far more than they need?

> Source 1: [The appearance of dolphin and whale meat in pet food indicates a clear lack of demand for the product from the public](http://www.bluevoice.org/news_petfood.php)
>
> Source 2: [Japanese Pets grow Fat on Dolphin Meat](http://www.whales.org.au/news/ajapanpet.html)
>
> Source 3: [Second we have been told by several sources that dolphin meat is also ground up and used in animal feeds](http://savejapandolphins.org/blog/post/dolphin-meat-cruel-toxic-and-wasteful)

Comment: I think I've heard people complaining that it's being "forced" upon schoolchildren in canteens, as if it's an unpopular food.

Comment: Original research, but I get 3 hits for [ドルフィン](http://cookpad.com/レシピ/ドルフィン) (dolphin) on cookpad. I might not be using the right word, though.

Comment: (About my first comment - that was about whale meat, not dolphins. Sorry.)

Comment: @AndrewGrimm - I think dolphin meat in local schools is mentioned in the popular The Cove documentary. Although they say it was then removed from school menus.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm None of the three hits use dolphin as ingredient though lol (e.g. one has a dolphin made out of carrot on it, etc.). Dolphins are only eaten in a very small, specific part of Japan. I have never heard of dolphin meat generally served in Japanese schools (as for whale, yes I had them in school and they taste horrible).